# Javascript: for loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Im currently trying to set up a loop that returns exif data from an image using [piexifjs](https://piexifjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Up to this point the code provided by the developer of piexif is working correct in my [Vue.js environment](https://github.com/annazeller/mediadb).

The loop which is used to display the exif-data inside the console looks like this:

```
for (let ifd in exifObj) {
    if (ifd == "thumbnail") {
        continue;
    }
    console.log("-" + ifd);
    for (let tag in exifObj[ifd]) {
        console.log("  " + piexif.TAGS[ifd][tag]["name"] + ":" + exifObj[ifd][tag]);
    }
}
```

Works fine, but if I try to edit it to return HTML and display the exif information on my Site it just returns one line of information. Here's the code:

```
for (let ifd in exifObj) {
    if (ifd === "thumbnail") {
        continue;
    }
    const   exifInfo = $(".modal-exif"),
            exifInfoDetail = $(".modal-exif-detail");
    exifInfo.html("&raquo; " + ifd);
    for (let tag in exifObj[ifd]) {
        exifInfoDetail.html("<li>" + piexif.TAGS[ifd][tag]["name"] + ":" + exifObj[ifd][tag] + "</li>");
    }
}
```

I guess my loop is overwriting itself where it returns just one value, which, I guess, is fine inside the console since but not inside HTML?

Anyone got any Idea hwo to change the loop to return one line for each entry?

Thank you :)

Comment: It isn't the for loop that isn't working. You just misunderstood how `jQuery.fn.html()` works. Read the [relevant documentation article](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for more information.

Comment: `.html()` overrides. So instead you should append to a string and do a final call to `.html()` when you have everything in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `console.log` case, each iteration is writing to the console, whereas in the `$(selector).html()` case, you are overwriting the html content per iteration. The jquery html function states:

> Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

That means that each iteration, the html content of `$(".modal-exif-detail")` is set to one single `"<li>" + piexif.TAGS[ifd][tag]["name"] + ":" + exifObj[ifd][tag] + "</li>"`.

You need to use something like [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) if you want to continually add to a node, or build up the html string and only execute one `html` after the loop